# How to use ticks in axes without specifying last value of tick?

Tags: matlab, plot, axis-labels

I've a problem with the axis settings in MATLAB. I want to have more ticks in my x and y axis than default in MATLAB. For that I used the following function

```
ax = gca;
ax.XTick = 0:0.5:max(xlim); 
ax.YTick = 0:0.5:max(ylim);
```

The Problem is my y axis starts not at 0 but at -0.5. I know I can define the XLim and YLim, but if I try the following code:

```
ax.XLim = [0 inf]
ax.YLim = [0 inf]
ax = gca;
ax.XTick = 0:0.5:max(xlim); 
ax.YTick = 0:0.5:max(ylim);
```

I get the following error:

```
Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.
Error in XXX
ax.YTick = 0:0.5:max(ylim);
```

I use `inf` because I don't know the last value. All I want is a plot that starts at 0 for both axes and ticks every 0.5.

Comment: I already tried axis tight. The Problem with that is if my variable reach as example 8.6, then is there a tick at 8.5 and the graph ends at 8.6. Looks horrible for me. Without tight the plot ends at 9 thats good. Just the start point is not 0. I know MATLAB does that automatic, but if I want to do it manual I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you simply wish to set the axis limits to start from 0, but don't want to change the upper limit.
You used the following set the axis ticks:

```
ax.XTick = 0:0.5:max(xlim);
```

Then you can use similar statement to set the limits:

```
ax.XLim = [0 max(xlim)];
```